# "Too many outcomes of parents (xxxx) can't display probabilities" error in weka tool

Tags: weka, graph-visualization, bayesian-networks

- I used bayes net for conditional probabilities and I got the Graph.
- But when i try to visualize the graph nothing appear on the screen and error "Too many outcomes of parents (xxxx) can't display probabilities" is displayed on the command line.
- As the data set that i am using is too large (99K rows in CSV file) thus the outcome of conditional probabilities is too high and cant be displayed.
- This error is due to the code used by weka for GraphVisualizer.java. By default if the outcome of the graph is more than 600 than the above error is displayed. So for that i need to change the GraphVisualizer.java in weka tools. Can anyone please help me with that.